# All it takes vs all it needs

Tags: grammaticality

What's the difference between these two -
1) . All it needs is for you to be more discreet . 
2) . All it takes is for you to be more discreet .

Comment: *All it needs* expresses the (minimal) **requirement** to ensure that "it" is corrected. *All it takes* expresses the (minimal) **effort** that is required to correct "it". In the context you give, there is no real difference. In other contexts, they may be.

Answer (score -1):

"All it needs..." is not idiomatic. However, "All you need..." is.

The difference is in the impersonal pronoun "it", which cannot "need" anything. Only a being can have needs. Therefore, it is correct to use "All ___ need[s]" with persons or animals.

"All it takes..." is correct because the "it" is referring to the situation or the potential circumstance--an abstract concept--which can have requirements, but not needs.

Comment: It would be useful for you to show support for the claim that "All it needs..." is not idiomatic. Google Ngrams show that "All it needs is for" is idiomatic and popular.